# Creating a method using Tuple that accepts a list of Point object and determines the smallest and largest for the given list's X and Y members

Tags: c#

I need to create a method with the following syntax using a Tuple.

```
public static Tuple<double, double, double, double> GetRectangeBounds(List<Point> points)
```

The goal here is to determine the smallest and largest values for the given list's X and Y members.  I have a created a struct called Point.  The struct Point has the following constructors

```
public struct Point
{
    double X;
    double Y;

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public Point(Point other)
    {
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
    }
 }
```

My question is how do access Points in the Tuple so I can make the comparisons which values are the smallest and largest given the lists X and Y members.  The tuple method must return the following.

```
return new Tuple<double, double, double, double>(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
```

Comment: It might be nice to define a `Rectangle` struct instead of using `Tuple<double,double,double,double>`.

Comment: Your point members are not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not altogether clear what your problem is, but all you need to do is declare four double variables `minX`, `maxX`, `minY` and `maxY`, set the mins to the `double.MaxValue` and the maxs to the `double.MinValue`, then loop through all points, check each x and y, and if either is less than minX or minY, update the variable as appropriate. Do the same for the maxs.

By the end of the loop, you'll have your values that you can return as a tuple.

```
public static Tuple<double, double, double, double> GetRectangeBounds(List<Point> points) {
    double minX = double.MaxValue;
    double minY = double.MaxValue;
    double maxX = double.MinValue;
    double maxY = double.MinValue;

    foreach (var point in points) {
        minX = Math.Min(minX, point.X);
        minY = Math.Min(minY, point.Y);
        maxX = Math.Max(maxX, point.X);
        maxY = Math.Max(maxY, point.Y);
    }

    return new Tuple<double, double, double, double>(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
}
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please update it to be clearer. Some sample input and output would help.

Note that if the static method is external to the `Point` class then you need to make the X and Y fields `public` properties in order to make them available externally

```
public struct Point {
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public Point(Point other) {
        X = other.X;
        Y = other.Y;
    }
}
```